# Apache to send an email notification on every HTTP error 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I configured apache to send an email notification on every HTTP error 500 using apache ErrorDocument and phpmailer script. It has been worked in my local machine, but when comes to the production server (ubuntu) it is not working since there is already a rewrite rule in .htacess file. Is there any way to run the ErrorDocument directive without removing the rewrite rule.

My .htaccess file rewrite rule is given below.

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

I need to add my custom php script redirection rule " ErrorDocument 500 /sendmail.php " in the .htaccess file.

Please help.

Comment: Why can't you simply add it? So what is _your real question_ here?

Comment: Since there is already a rewrite rule in the htaccess file, the error document is not working

Comment: Both things are independent.

Comment: Both arw independent but only rule writing first in the htaccess is working fine. Both are not working at the same time

Comment: I fail to see a reason for such behavior. Both aspects can be combined on a per directory base, if you really have to. And they both work fine _if enabled in the server's host configuration..._ Since you did not post your attempt we cannot say more here.

Comment: But in my case they are not working together. If you don't mind could you please write a htaccess file with the code I have given above and the error document

Comment: As said: there is no magic in this. If things don't work the way you expect you will need to start debugging, there is no assistance I can provide in that. I suggest you enable rewrite logging to learn the details of what is going on inside your rewriting engine.